# Would the slang version, yessir, of yes, sir, be deemed as derogatory, offensive, or simply disrespectful to someone your senior?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, slang

I use *yessir* as a slang form of *yes, sir* all the time.

1. Is it even a word?
2. Would the slang version, *yessir*, be deemed as derogatory, offensive, or simply disrespectful to someone your senior?

Comment: "Yassuh, Massa!". It's a bit stereotypical, imho.

Comment: Then, there's that ... yea ... another form, but that one is obviously racially charged =D

Comment: It made *me* think of it that way. Who says your superiors at work won't have the same reaction?

Comment: Depends on your accent I suppose.  I don't pronounce `ir` as `uh`.

Comment: Kindly refrain from using ugly blue monospace code markup in lieu of italic. There is no code to be formatted here, so please stop doing that. One uses an italic face to distinguish uses from mentions if at all possible, and quotes otherwise.  One does not use **`UGLY BLUE MONOSPACE`** for that purpose — not ever! Thank you.

Comment: I'm not even thinking about the accent - the only clue I'm going on is you've written the two words with no space. To me, that slurring together is recognisable (and probably has similar connotations) regardless of accent.

Comment: @tchrist: What are you, the font police? Stop filling up my nice tidy display with a load of [characters that don't display properly]. :)

Comment: Yea ... the interesting thing is the link I have to the definition in my answer says that it's used to "express emphatic affirmation."

Comment: I think that's *"Yes, **SIR!**"*

Comment: @tchrist - Sorry, I thought it was a way to do the distinguishing for ELU, my bad.  It's a habit from SO! =D

Comment: @CodeMaverick Don’t worry: it’s a common thing that newcomers from Stack Overflow tend to do without thinking. It’s a holdover habit from coding SE sites that’s sometimes hard to break. We use italic for “literals” here, the way dictionaries, encyclopedias, and linguistics journals do.  You really should not be using code markup for emphasis anywhere; this is talked about on Meta.SE somewhere I forget just right now. Best to leave code markup to . . . code. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Ok](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z3rj.png).

Comment: @tchrist - You mean, "[yessir](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z3rj.png)!"

Comment: @tchrist: I'm currently [deeply suspicious](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/) of the display capabilities of the machine I'm using. Tomorrow, I'll have a look at your first comment here on my other machine (with freshly-installed fully updated Win7 replacing previous Vista). Mind you, I think I *have* seen "upside-down" text posted by you (can't remember if it was in a *comment*), so I assume my kit has *some* competence. Yeah, yeah - I know the smarts are mostly your input, not my output. :)

Comment: And how derogatory might _yes, Sir, Mrs. Sir, yes, Sir!_ be considered? And by God does it have at least twice as many commas as it needs!

Comment: /'yɛsər/ is how it's pronounced. It's intended to be pronounced, because the important thing about it is that it is a mark at least of personal respect in speech, and in many circumstances, personal obeisance. That is, it's important that one ***says*** it. How you spell it is up to you; English spelling is not very good at representing actual speech, and probly anything understandable will work when reporting (or attempting to imitate) real speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler The OED even has citations for the verb, of which one is: **1980 H. R. F. Keating** *Murder of Maharajah* xv. 182 ― You’re used to people yessirring you left and right.

Comment: "Yessir" is simply "yes" and "sir" slurred together.  It would only be disrespectful when full formality (and careful enunciation) was expected (eg, in a military ceremony).

Comment: It is all context and will be interpreted within an array of factors.

Answer (score 4):

1. [It is definitely a word](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/yessir):

   > ## yessir
   >
   > Syllabification: yes·sir
   >
   > Pronunciation: /ˈyesər, ˈyesˈsər
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Definition of *yessir* in English:
   > **EXCLAMATION**
   >
   > 1. Used to [express](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/express#express) [assent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/assent):
   >
   >    *“Do you understand me?” “Yessir!”*
   >
   >    1.1. *North American* Used to [express](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/express#express) [emphatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/emphatic) [affirmation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/affirmation):
   >
   >    *'yessir the food was cheap'*

2. I tend to think that it would be, as the whole point of saying *yes, sir*, in the first place, is to show respect.  So it would stand to reason that using the slang version, *yessir*, that logically it makes sense that it would be, if not derogatory, offensive or disrespectful in certain situations.

   That said, I might be thinking about it all wrong, as from the link above, it states that it's used to *express emphatic affirmation*.  So maybe they are equals where *yessir* is simply just a more *emphatic* way of saying *yes, sir*.

Comment: I just thought it conveyed a certain sense of urgency or enthusiasm.

Comment: I can see that.

Comment: You shouldn’t forget that you can yessir someone as a verb, and that the antonym *nossir* also exists.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not _forgetting_ nor _intentionally_ leaving _nossir_ out, it just wasn't my question.

Comment: I'd associate it partly with the military, where shouting "yes sir" at a superior office is a required action regardless of what you're asked to do, rather than a communication indicating agreement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about you all but the short answer to this based on my personal experience is that is has become derogatory, offensive, and disrespectful.

In the past, people used to say it looking you in the eye and with sincerity. Now it's like it's a sarcastic way of saying "screw you, you're not the boss of me". Most cases, the person will be walking away saying this, not looking you directly in the eye or at least facing you. Sad state of affairs we live in today. Almost everyone I've come across says it in a negative and inscincere tone.