# "Yes sir" usage

Tags: connotation, politeness

I have heard "Yes, sir." used by a client or by the older participant in a conversation and it seems to me that this goes against the common usage. What is the connotation of "Yes, sir." in a contemporary context, used between peers?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216427/would-the-slang-version-yessir-of-yes-sir-be-deemed-as-derogatory-offensive

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more context. The expression may be very appropriate or rather odd, according to the opinions of the observer.

Comment: Agreed, it does require more context to answer. But to briefly answer what I think you're asking: when used in such a manner, i.e, as you would define as "against the common usage", such as by an older participant, it often slightly lightens the tone of the conversation (or is used when the conversation already is casual: see comment by user159691).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used *between peers*, "yes, sir" has multiple connotations that depend on context, often very subtly.

1. When being ironical or flippant when the person making the response feels they have been given a command by someone who has no right to command. In this case it would be a rebuke to the person giving the command, perhaps in case they hadn't noticed they were being rude.

   > A. (Said in a peremptory tone of voice) Ron, hand me that book.
   >   B. (Ironically) Yes, sir! (B makes mock salute)
2. When said individual enthusiastically endorses a suggestion made by a peer.

   > A. I think you ought to be promoted to tech lead. You're smarter than Michael.
   >   B. Yes, sir!
3. When said individual wants to comment on the remarkable nature of something.

   > A. I see the U.S. is pulling out of the global climate agreement.
   >   B. Yes, sir. That actually happened.
4. When said individual is pleased about a circumstance.

   > A. I see you got a new sports car.
   >   B. Yes, sir! Want to take a ride?

There are others, of course, but this should give you an idea of actual usage. The important thing to remember is that "yes, sir" is almost never used at face value, i.e., in a peer-to-peer situation where one is responding to being given a command and conveying actual respect *unless the command was given for the benefit of the person addressed*.

5. Example:

   > A. Don't touch the green wire! It's live!
   >   B. Yes, sir! Whew, that was close!

Comment: 'Yes, sir!' etc can even be used when there is no real dialogue as an emphatic form, equivalent of the German 'Jawohl!' From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yessir): << North American Used to express emphatic affirmation.
‘yessir the food was cheap’ >>